# There are missing files when I archived from custom build configuration

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, archive

We have different build configurations in our project, like the `release`, `debug`, `sandbox`, etc. The interesting case is when I archived from the `release` or `debug` build configuration, all archive files extracted as expected as shown in *Image 1*, but If I change build configuration to `sandbox`, some files and folders are missing as shown in *Image 2*.

Although we created custom build configurations by duplicating from `debug` or `release`, the archive doesn't contain all files or folders like in *Image 1*.

We use `carthage`(for internal network) and `cocoapods`(for others) as a dependency manager.

[image]

I tried many suggestions but couldn't find a solution.

Like,

setting `skip install` to `NO` in build settings,
removing all archive and derived data files, clean and re-archive,
giving the archive folder to `read & write` permission

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Carthage for internal frameworks you should have same custom build configurations for them, too. Otherwise, it will bootstrap with `Release` configuration automatically which won't generate SwiftSupport files etc.

You also can avoid this by adding below before archiving in your custom configurations.

`carthage bootstrap --configuration Debug`

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that those files are included in `Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but It's already like that.